# JavaScript: comma after opening bracket of parameter in syntax example

Tags: javascript, syntax

The syntax for methods such as [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) look like this:

`arr.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex = 0])`

What does `[, ...]` mean, and why is the comma inside of the brackets?

Comment: The brackets indicate that any fields inside the brackets are optional. The comma indicates that the properties need to be separated by a comma. You **do not** put those brackets into live code.

Comment: This syntax is only for *documentation* and has nothing to do with JavaScript itself. Different documentation systems may choose to encode/display optional arguments and default values differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The brackets themselves mean "optional", and the `= 0` gives the default value should you decide to omit that parameter. The reason why the comma is inside the brackets is because it forms part of the optional bit - if the second parameter is omitted, so is the comma.

In other words, you can use `indexOf` with *only* `searchElement`, in which case `fromIndex` is assumed to be zero. Or you can specify your *own* value for `fromIndex` if you don't want to start searching at element number zero.

So the first two below are equivalent while the third will start searching at a different point in the array:

```
x = haystack.indexOf (needle);
x = haystack.indexOf (needle, 0);
x = haystack.indexOf (needle, 42);
```

The Mozilla Developer Network has [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to say on the matter (my emphasis):

> `fromIndex:` The index to start the search at.
>
> If the index is greater than or equal to the array's length, -1 is returned, which means the array will not be searched. If the provided index value is a negative number, it is taken as the offset from the end of the array.
>
> Note: if the provided index is negative, the array is still searched from front to back. If the calculated index is less than 0, then the whole array will be searched.
>
> *Default: 0 (entire array is searched).*

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex = 0])
```

Bracket is used to indicate that it's optional to use. And the comma is used to separate the argument.

For eg. you use both then you'd do like this:

```
arr.indexOf(searchElement, fromIndex)
```

Or,

```
//omitting fromIndex use the default to 0
arr.indexOf(searchElement)//As fromIndex is optional to use
```

Answer (score 1):

This is to represent multiple function signatures. Those inside `[]` are optional parameters. So that means either you could invoke it like:

```
arr.indexOf(searchElement) // in such case fromIndex is 0 by default
```

or, you could invoke with two arguments:

```
arr.indexOf(searchElement, fromIndex)
```